# UIScrollView subview to adjust to super view frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview

I have a UIScrollView in which it has a UIImageView as a subview, I've been changing the frame size of the UIScrollView but I wanted the UIImageView to adjust to this as well. How do I do this?

Comment: What do you want the scroll view to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: the imageView is your UIImageView in the UIScrollView

Answer (score 0):

```
[imageView setFrame:[scrollView bounds]];
```

Comment: will changing the autoresizing mask help?

Comment: It might, try it. However, the idea sounds weird. Why would you need a scroll view at all? It cannot scroll anything if the subview's frame follows its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

First set  the frame of UIScrollView, set scrollview frame to image view like -

```
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
    imageView.frame = scrollView.frame;
```

I think it will help.